# pandas ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis when trying to do calculation based on values from another df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 `df`s:

```
df2
dec_pl    cur_key
0         JPY
1         HKD

df1
cur    amount
JPY    80
HKD    20
USD    70
```

I like to reference `del_pl` in `df2` for 'cur' in `df1`, and calculate `df1.converted_amount = df1.amount * 10 ** (2 - df2.dec_pl)` for `df1`; i.e. `df1.amount` times the 10 to the power of `(2 - df2.dec_pl)` and if there cannot find a corresponding `df2.cur_key` from `df1.cur`, e.g. `USD`, then just use its amount;

```
df1 = df1.set_index('cur')
df2 = df2.set_index('cur_key')
df1['converted_amount'] = (df1.amount*10**(2 - df2.dec_pl)).fillna(df1['amount'], downcast='infer')
```

but i got

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

I am wondering whats the best way to do this, so the results should look like,

```
df1
cur    amount    converted_amount
JPY    80        8000
HKD    20        200
USD    70        70
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On possible problem is duplicates in `cur_key` column, like:

```
print (df2)
   dec_pl cur_key
0       0     HKD
1       1     HKD


df1 = df1.set_index('cur')
```

Solutions are aggregation duplicates for unique `cur_key` - e.g. by `sum`:

```
df2 = df2.groupby('cur_key').sum()
```

Or remove duplicates - keep only first or last values per `cur_key`:

```
#first default value
df2 = df2.drop_duplicates('cur_key').set_index('cur_key')
#last value
#df2 = df2.drop_duplicates('cur_key', keep='last').set_index('cur_key')
```

---

```
df1['converted_amount'] = (df1.amount*10**(2 - df2.dec_pl)).fillna(df1['amount'], downcast='infer')
print (df1)
     amount  converted_amount
cur                          
JPY      80                80
HKD      20               200
USD      70                70
```